# AVFoundation and request of microphone

Tags: swift, avfoundation, microphone

I have a problem about the AVFoundation

```
import AVFoundation

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()  
    setUpAudio()
}

func setUpAudio() {

    do {
        playCorrect = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "correct", ofType: "mp3")!))
        playCorrect.prepareToPlay()
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }

}
```

When launching the app, it appears

[image]

I don't know which line of code trigger the request of microphone.

My app doesn't need access of microphone. How can I make the request box disappear??

I have tried "DON'T ALLOW" the request, and my app worked fine.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but you should change `URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "correct", ofType: "mp3")!` to `Bundle.main.url(forResource: "correct", withExtension: "mp3")!`. Also, including an English screenshot would also help future readers, since the language of the site is English and being able to see and read the actual error message would help.

Comment: Seems the issue is a bug with the simulator. There is a long thread here...https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/110423